# Tomcat: custom error page instead of empty response

Tags: java, http, tomcat, response

Some requests are rejected by Tomcat with an **empty** HTTP `400` response.

A couple of examples:

A request url containing unencoded characters (e.g. '[' or ']' since Tomcat 8.5.x) triggers:

```
INFO  o.a.c.h.Http11Processor   Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
```

A 400 error page is also returned for example when the header size is too large:

```
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
```

Is it possible to have a custom error page for those errors? More generally for when Tomcat triggers this HTTP 400 response. Delivering an empty response is the worst UX. I am aware that the creation of such requests should be avoided, but I am nonetheless looking for a fallback.

I have set up a custom error page in my (embedded) Tomcat context with `ctx.addErrorPage(...)` for the error code `400`.

It works properly when triggered from my webapp.
E.g. when delegating the error handling to the servlet error handling mechanism with `res.sendError(SC_BAD_REQUEST);` - `res` being a `HttpServletResponse`.

Unfortunately for the kind of tomcat errors described at the top, the custom error page is not used.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/254102/custom-error-pages-on-apache-tomcat)?

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned the configuration of my 400 custom error page generally works. It is however not used when Tomcat triggers the error like in the examples I listed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nuisance to me as well. Unfortunately, from having a look at the sources, it seems to be wired deep in Tomcat's internals, and can't be changed easily.

In particular, the exceptions you note are thrown in `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer`, which is part of one of Tomcat's component called the [Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/coyote.html) (old docs, newer docs don't have this):

> The Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector element represents a Connector component
>   that supports the HTTP/1.1 protocol. It enables Catalina to function
>   as a stand-alone web server, in addition to its ability to execute
>   servlets and JSP pages.

Also, the exceptions end up in `catalina.log` and are very short - compare this to when you get an exception from the JSP processor, which are several times that size.

So I think it isn't trivial to patch this - at least not without knowledge about Tomcat internals, which I don't have :(

Comment: I am glad to see that I am not the only one struggling with this!